# Dojo: widget instances share the same variable

Tags: javascript, dojo

There is a custom `Foo` widget defined, which has local `bar' value. And an onClick function that changes 'bar' to something.

Now, multiple instances of `Foo` are defined declarative inside an HTML-template like this:

```
<input id="foo1" data-dojo-type="path-to-wiget/Foo">
<input id="foo2" data-dojo-type="path-to-wiget/Foo">
<input id="foo3" data-dojo-type="path-to-wiget/Foo">
```

The problem is that each of those inputs should have its own instance of `foo` variable, but for some reason they behave like there only one!

```
>> clicking foo1 -> foo1.foo = 'bar'
>> clicking foo2 -> foo2.foo = 'baz'.. but foo1.foo is set to 'baz' as well.. why?
```

How to make sure, each widget has its own `foo` variable?

Comment: Can you add the widget code here? I think I might know the answer, but I don't have enough information to anwser.

Comment: Sounds like it's down to where that variable is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you have not added your code for `Foo.js` so it is difficult to understand your issue.

But if you are going for a declarative approach `data-dojo-type` you could consider passing your property per instance using `data-dojo-props`.

In the following example, you pass the value of `myProp` in your HTML markup, you can see that is being added to the property instance when you retrieve it using `dijit/registry`.

Example, please open console:

https://jsfiddle.net/e5dx8nue/

```
<input id="foo1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="myProp: 'foo1'">
<input id="foo2" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="myProp: 'foo2'">
<input id="foo3" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="myProp: 'foo3'">
```

---

```
require(['dojo/parser', 'dijit/registry'], function(parser, registry) {
  parser.parse().then(function() {
    var widget1 = registry.byId('foo1'); // print foo1
    var widget2 = registry.byId('foo2'); // print foo2
    var widget3 = registry.byId('foo3'); // print foo3
    console.log(widget1.myProp);
    console.log(widget2.myProp);
    console.log(widget3.myProp);
  });
});
```

More information on [declarative syntax can be found here](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declarative/).